# В чём заключается смысл remain?

Tags: c++

```
if (remainA == 0)
    cout<<"A = четное число "<<endl;
else cout<<"A = Число нечетное"<<endl;
```

Для чего тут remain? Что оно вообще делает?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что данный вопрос несёт пользу только автору и бесполезен для других.

Comment: Судя по всему, автор кода хотел написать `remainder` (остаток по-английски). Но ему не хватило букв.

Comment: Я тоже не понимаю, зачем так много букв? Смотрите, ведь так : `cout << "A = " << (A % 2 ? "не" : "") << "четное число\n";` или даже так:
  `printf("A = %sчетное число\n", A & 1 ? "не" : "");` значительно проще.

Comment: Буков ему хватило. Но в блокноте нет автокомплита, а полностью печатать везде remainder_of_A рука быстро устанет, пришлось сократить.

Answer (score 3):

Судя по всему remain- остаток от деления. При делении на два у чётного числа остаток 0. У нечётного 1

Comment: Поправьте - "у НЕчётного 1"

Comment: @Denis, спасибо, исправил

Answer (score 2):

> Для чего тут remain? Что оно вообще делает?

В приведенном вами фрагменте кода идентификатор `remain` отсутствует.:) Вместо него используется идентификатор `remainA`.

```
if (remainA == 0)
    ^^^^^^^^  
    cout<<"A = четное число "<<endl;
else cout<<"A = Число нечетное"<<endl;
```

Судя по контексту данная переменная хранит остаток от деления значения в переменной `A` на 2. Есои значение этой переменной четное, то остаток от деления на 2 будет равным 0. То есть переменная `remainA`, значение которой вычисляется в соответствии с логикой следующего предложения,

```
remainA = A % 2;
```

будет равно 0.

В противном случае если переменная `A`  хранит нечетное число, то остаток от деления на 2 будет равен 1, и переменная `remainA` будет хранить это значение остатка, то есть 1.

В зависимости от хранимого в переменной `remainA` значения остатка от деления на 2 значения числа, хранимого в переменной `A`, на консоль выводится сообщение, является ли это хранимое число четным или нечетным.